# mandrill - handlebars how can i iterate over 2 dimension array?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mandrill

Say I have this array:

```
var arr = [
    [1,4,6,8,3,9,1],
    [2,4,6,7,3,2,7]
];
```

And I want to iterate over it with mandrill -> handlebar #each how will I do it ?

so far I have something like

```
{{#each arr}}
    {{#each this}}
        {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

the above will output the desired result but when I add a condition inside the second each `this` value changes to an array I assume it takes the parent this - not sure.

```
{{#each arr}}
    {{#each this}}
        {{#if @first}}
            <div>{{this}} - first</div>
        {{else}}
            <div>{{this}}</div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

More over when I use normal handlebars it works perfectly fine.
E.G. http://jsfiddle.net/ccrmwont/2/

This is pretty specific issue I know but I am stuck with this for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the index in your second iteration:

```
{{#each arr}}
{{#each 0}}
    {{#if @first}}
        <div>{{0.0}} - first element in first array</div>
        <div>{{0.1}} - second element in first array</div>
{{/each}}
{{#each 1}}
        <div>{{1.0}} -first element in second array</div>
        <div>{{1.1}} -second element in second array</div>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I dont think Mandrill yet supports full handlebars functionality, this is probably the best way to do this at the moment. See more here:

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content